# Fetching Multi level related records laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I am using Laravel 8.
I have 3 tables **users**, **campaigns** and **payments**

> User has many Campaigns and Campaign has many payments
> table Payments has campaign_id and table campaigns has user_id

I want to fetch auth user payment details but table payments does not consist user_id but campaign_id.

How do I get these details?

Comment: please share you relationships to give you best solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your query is so simple
if you are using eloquent eelationships
try this line of code

```
\Auth::user()->campaigns()->payments();
```

if you want to do that manualy

```
User::query()
                ->join('campaigns c' , 'c.user_id' , '=' , 'users.id')
                ->join('payments p' , 'p.campaign_id ' , '=' , 'c.payment_id')
                ->get(['p.*']);
```